# Copying directories between two areas in Perforce Depot

Tags: copy, perforce

I have two areas:

```
//depot/path/to/area1/...
//depot/another/path/to/area2/...
```

I work in both areas, and need to copy files in both areas back and forth. I assumed a

```
p4 copy //depot/path/to/area1/... //depot/another/path/to/area2
```

would do that, but when I "p4 sync" in the second area nothing downloads. I check in p4v, but don't see anything in the changelists.

Does anyone know how to do this?

*Yes I know I should not have the same files in two areas, but that is out of my control.

Comment: I tried doing it to individual files and it works. Can anyone comment if this is the only way?

Comment: `p4 copy //depot/path1/... //depot/path2/...` creates copies in my client for me.  Why would you need to sync to download the files?  They should be copied in the client already.  Or maybe you forgot to submit the change that branches the files and are trying to sync from a different client?

Comment: Is there a typo in your question, or did you forget the second elipsis wildcard in your 'p4 copy' command? And don't forget to submit.

Comment: Due to integration in a bug tracking tool, I have to submit seperately. I was forgetting to submit, and trying to submit in a different client and I think that was the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to integrate/copy files/changes from //depot/path/to/area1/... to //depot/another/path/to/area2/... you need to call:

```
p4 copy //depot/path/to/area1/... //depot/another/path/to/area2/...
p4 submit
```

You need to do that in a client that has the targetpath in its clientview.
The targetpath is //depot/another/path/to/area2/...

Comment: yes, I think that last part was my issue. Do you know if this operation can be spread across multiple clients?

Comment: No - you open files in your client and you can only submit them from that same client (it wouldn't make sense to do that).